# Cant decode/encode query commas with react-query-params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, ecmascript-6, next.js

Im stucked 3 days already on this. I cant put in browser decoded URL parameter. I need just put string in the browser URL. I Have problems with commas symbol.

Im using react-query-params and qs.stringify for a string

```
  const filtrToClientQuery = qs.stringify(
    { ...filterActive },
    { arrayFormat: "comma", delimiter: ";" }


  const decodefiltrToClientQuery = decodeURIComponent(filtrToClientQuery);
```

This is result decodefiltrToClientQuery string what i want to put in client browser (in console.log result is fine)

```
"color=red,yellow;resolution=1024"
```

But when i put query in browser with setQuery

```
       <button
              className="set-btn"
              onClick={() => setQuery(decodefiltrToClientQuery)}
            >
              setFilter
            </button>
```

Then i get this result

```
foo=color%3Dred%2Cyellow%3Bresolution%3D1024
```

Im really stuck on this long time. Can somebody habe some solution?

Comment: can you create a codesandbox example?